# Finding number representation in different bases

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I was recently solving a problem when I encountered this one: [APAC Round E Q2](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/5264487/dashboard#s=p1)

Basically the question asks to find the smallest base (>1) in which if the number (input) is written then the number would only consist of 1s. Like 3 if represented in base 2 would become 1 (consisting of only 1s).

Now, I tried to solve this the brute force way trying out all bases from 2 till the number to find such a base. But the constraints required a more efficient one.

Can anyone provide some help on how to approach this?

Comment: I guess this question will be closed soon. There is another site with the specification of programming puzzles http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this in `O( (log2 n)^2 )` complexity by recognizing that the highest power attainable in the sequence would correspond with the smallest base, `2`, and using the formula for geometric sum:

```
1 + r + r^2 + r^3 ... + r^(n-1) = (1 - r^n) / (1 - r)

Renaming the variables, we get: 

  n = (1 - base^power) / (1 - base)
```

Now we only need to check `power`'s from `(floor(log2 n) + 1)` down to `2`, and for each given power, use a binary search for the base. For example:

```
n = 13:

  p = floor(log2 13) + 1 = 4:

    Binary search for base:

    (1 - 13^4) / (1 - 13) = 2380

    ...

    No match for power = 4. 

    Try power = 3:

    (1 - 13^3) / (1 - 13) = 183

    (1 - 6^3) / (1 - 6) = 43

    (1 - 3^3) / (1 - 3) = 13 # match
```

For `n` around `10^18` we may need up to `(floor(log2 (10^18)) + 1)^2 = 3600` iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one suggestion: A number `x` that can be represented as all `1`s in a base `b` can be written as `x = b^n + b^(n-1) + b^(n-2) + ... + b^1 + 1`

If you subtract `1` from this number you end up with a number divisble by `b`:
`b^n + b^(n-1) + b^(n-2) + ... + b^1` which has the representation `111...110`. Dividing by `b` means shifting it right once so the resulting number is now `b^(n-1) + b^(n-2) + ... + b^1` or `111...111` with one digit less than before. Now you can repeat the process until you reach `0`.

For example `13` which is `111` in base `3`:

```
13 - 1 = 12 --> 110
12 / 3 = 4  -->  11
 4 - 1 = 3  -->  10
 3 / 3 = 1  -->   1
 1 - 1 = 0  -->   0
Done => 13 can be represented as all 1s in base 3
```

So in order to check if a given number can be written with all `1`s in a base `b` you can check if that number is divisble by `b` after subtracting `1`. If not you can immediately start with the next base.

This is also pretty brute-forcey but it doesn't do any base conversions, only one subtraction, one divisions and one mod operation per iteration.